# Completely center an image using CSS?

Tags: html, css

I know this is a noob-ish question but is it possible to fully center an image to the absolute center of a webpage no matter how much the page/window is changed using CSS? I'm working with a simple  tag and I need to know how to? I've been looking around Google but I'm not getting any relevant results, probably due to my lack of correct phrasing...

I need it centred both horizontally and vertically.

Thanks!

Comment: Should it be in front of everything or behind everything?

Comment: It's pretty much just social link icons that I want to be centred completely on the page.

Comment: horizontally, vertically or both?

Comment: Yep, I need then both. That's what I'm having trouble with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To centre elements:

```
.className {
    width:200px; /*Set to image width*/
    height:100px; /*Set to image height*/
    position:absolute; 
    top:50%; 
    left:50%; 
    margin:-50px auto auto -100px; /*Half of image width, 0, 0, half of image height*/
    text-align:center;
}
```

HTML:

```
<img src="whatever.jpg" class="className" />
```

JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Mutant_Tractor/xBRq9/

Comment: Nope, that only centres it to to the centre at the top. I want it to be centred vertically and horizontally.

Comment: @dbramhall - See revision above

Comment: We're getting there :) That's aligns it vertically now had do I go about it horizontally?

Comment: Boom! Works! Finally! Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

A. To center a background (it usually is a good idea to center images like this):

```
background-image: url(your/image.ext);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center;
```

B. Inline elements (span, img, a) can be centered horizontally by setting `text-align: center;` on the parent.

C. HTML block elements can be centered horizontally with

```
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
```

Centering vertically is a [bit more complex](http://www.wpdfd.com/editorial/thebox/deadcentre4.html).

Comment: This will use the image as the background of your page, with all other content on top of this image. Just FYI, Asker.

Comment: Nope, don't want to a background to be centred just an image. Both vertically and horizontally.

Comment: @dbramhall If you want vertical centering see the link in the answer. You need a bit of CSS-foo for that.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it this way:

```
img.class-name{

    position: absolute;
    margin: auto;
    left: 0; 
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nWWef/1/)

You need to make a div and position it with

> text-align:centre;

and then you can centre your image vertically within the div like in the fiddle

Answer (score 0):

*If you want to center image to the center regardless of screen size, you can try out this code*

```
img{
   display: flex;
   justify-content:center;
   align-items: center;
   height: 100vh;
}
```